# How to move the address of authors in the footnote of the first page?

Tags: header-footer, titles, amsart

I want that the address will be in the footnote of the first page

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
%------------------------------------------------------------
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \makeatletter
   \patchcmd\maketitle
      {\uppercasenonmath\shorttitle}
        {}
        {}{}
  \patchcmd\maketitle
        {\@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\toks@}}
       {\the\toks@}
         {}
         {}{}
    %----
   %\patchcmd\@settitle
   %  {\uppercasenonmath\@title}
   % {}
   %  {}{}
    \patchcmd\@setauthors
          {\MakeUppercase{\authors}}
          {\authors}
           {}{}
 \makeatother
  %------------------------------------------------------------
 %\usepackage[notref,notcite]{showkeys}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage{url}
   %-----------------               
  %------------------------------------------------------------
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   %------------------------------------------------------------
 \usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}

%-------------------------------------------
 \address{$^{[1]}$ The address of author1.}
  \email{\url{Author1@....com}}
    \address{$^{[2]}$ The address of author2.}
 \email{\url{Author2@....com}}

 \subjclass[2010]{......}

    \keywords{......}

  %%%%%%%%%%%% \begin{document} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \begin{document}
 \author[Author1, Author2] {Author1$^{1}$ and Author2$^{2}$ }
 \title{Title}
 \maketitle
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  \documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
%------------------------------------------------------------
   \usepackage{etoolbox}

   %---------- To move the authors addresses to the footnote ----------

   \makeatletter

\appto\maketitle{%
\let\@makefnmark\relax  \let\@thefnmark\relax
\ifx\@empty\addresses\else\@footnotetext{%
  \vskip-\bigskipamount\@setaddresses}
  }
\def\enddoc@text{}
\makeatother

%-----------------------end -------------------

   \makeatletter
   \patchcmd\maketitle
    {\uppercasenonmath\shorttitle}
     {}
    {}{}
    \patchcmd\maketitle
    {\@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\toks@}}
   {\the\toks@}
       {}
      {}{}
        %----
     %\patchcmd\@settitle
     %  {\uppercasenonmath\@title}
     % {}
      %  {}{}
      \patchcmd\@setauthors
       {\MakeUppercase{\authors}}
     {\authors}
       {}{}
     \makeatother
      %------------------------------------------------------------
     %\usepackage[notref,notcite]{showkeys}
   \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
      \usepackage{color}
      \usepackage{url}
       %-----------------               
      %------------------------------------------------------------
      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
       %------------------------------------------------------------
     \usepackage{geometry}
       \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}

    %-------------------------------------------
     \address{$^{[1]}$ The address of author1.}
      \email{\url{Author1@....com}}
        \address{$^{[2]}$ The address of author2.}
     \email{\url{Author2@....com}}

     \subjclass[2010]{......}

        \keywords{......}




      %%%%%%%%%%%% \begin{document} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \begin{document}
     \author[Author1, Author2] {Author1$^{1}$  and Author2$^{2}$ }
     \title{Title}

     \maketitle


        \end{document}
```

[image]

**Update to typeset the addresses in lowercase**

```
 \documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
%------------------------------------------------------------
   \usepackage{etoolbox}

   %---------- To move the authors addresses to the footnote ----------

   \makeatletter

 \patchcmd{\@setaddresses}{\scshape\ignorespaces}{\ignorespaces}{}{} % addresses in lowercase

\appto\maketitle{%
\let\@makefnmark\relax  \let\@thefnmark\relax
\ifx\@empty\addresses\else\@footnotetext{%
  \vskip-\bigskipamount\@setaddresses}
  }
\def\enddoc@text{}
\makeatother

%-----------------------end -------------------

   \makeatletter
   \patchcmd\maketitle
    {\uppercasenonmath\shorttitle}
     {}
    {}{}
    \patchcmd\maketitle
    {\@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\toks@}}
   {\the\toks@}
       {}
      {}{}
        %----
     %\patchcmd\@settitle
     %  {\uppercasenonmath\@title}
     % {}
      %  {}{}
      \patchcmd\@setauthors
       {\MakeUppercase{\authors}}
     {\authors}
       {}{}

     \makeatother
      %------------------------------------------------------------
     %\usepackage[notref,notcite]{showkeys}
   \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
      \usepackage{color}
      \usepackage{url}
       %-----------------               
      %------------------------------------------------------------
      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
       %------------------------------------------------------------
     \usepackage{geometry}
       \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}

    %-------------------------------------------
     \address{$^{[1]}$ The address of author1.}
      \email{\url{Author1@....com}}
        \address{$^{[2]}$ The address of author2.}
     \email{\url{Author2@....com}}

     \subjclass[2010]{......}

        \keywords{......}




      %%%%%%%%%%%% \begin{document} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \begin{document}
     \author[Author1, Author2] {Author1$^{1}$  and Author2$^{2}$ }
     \title{Title}

     \maketitle


        \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to take the address of authors in lowercase letters and not in capital letters?

Comment: @Schüler  answer updated

Comment: @Schüler. If the answer fixes your problem please consider upvoting and/or marking it as *accepted!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.